# how to add next and prev pages in our single blog post in django

Tags: python, django, web

i wanna add next and prev pages in my single blog post

and i tried something but dose not work so well

and this my url that i made for my site  [http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/](http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/5)pid

views.py

```
def blog_single(request, pid):
    post = blog_Post.objects.get(published_date__lte=timezone.now(), status=1, pk=pid)
    post.counted_views += 1
    post.save()
context = {'post':post}
return render(request, "blog/blog-single.html", context)
```

i try this

```
   
next_post = blog_Post.objects.filter(id__gt=post.id).order_by('id').first()
   
prev_post = blog_Post.objects.filter(id__lt=post.id).order_by('id').last()
```

but it dose not work

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add pagination when you have only one instance.

Comment: i have many posts in my database

Comment: What you want to apply pagination on ? I see you are getting first and last item of a queryset.

Comment: also why you doing greater than and less than on a primary key ? It seems weird

Comment: you can search how to apply pagination on the data. it will need changes in the views as well as in the JS file